# How to return reference to a function in ActionScript to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript

If I want to return a reference to an arbitrary function in ActionScript to JavaScript, what should I have to do?

For example, I can make an object with some method functions.

```
function maker()
{
    const o = {};
    o.a = function() {};
    o.b = function() {};
    return o;
}
```

I can do same thing in both of JavaScript and ActionScript. But If I send the object made in ActionScript to JavaScript via `ExternalInterface`, it will be just an empty object. It's members disappears. How can I return those reference to functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

The best thing to do is to store your function in a dictionary and pass the key, as a string, out through the external interface.  Your JavaScript code can then invoke a dispatcher function with the key, to cause your AS code to call the right function.